# Neo4j: Return nodes that don't exist in a collection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to answer the question: What actors in my database are not within 12 degrees from Kevin Bacon. What I've tried to do is collect all the actors that are within 12 degrees from Kevin Bacon and subtract them from the total number of actors in the database. Unfortunately, I've been doing something wrong, because no subtraction actually goes on and the number of results returns actually increases. I'm using this database: https://neo4j.com/developer/movie-database/

Here's my code:

```
MATCH shortestPath((connectingActor:Actor)-[:ACTS_IN*1..24]-(bacon:Actor {name: 'Kevin Bacon'})) 
WHERE connectingActor <> bacon 
WITH collect(DISTINCT connectingActor) as connectingActors  
MATCH (actors:Actor) 
WHERE connectingActors <> actors 
RETURN DISTINCT actors.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. The problem is in your WHERE clause just before your RETURN.

Your current WHERE clause is comparing :Actor nodes to your list of `connectingActors`, and since a node is never a list, no :Actors will be filtered.

What you need is to test for membership in the list:

```
 ...
 WHERE NOT actors in connectingActors
 ...
```